# display string of rgb values as image matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list of 3 digit long lists that represent RGB values. I want to know if I can use matplotlib to display those RGB values.

Example list:

```py
[
[[125, 237, 145], [192, 248, 234]],
[[203, 157, 175], [84, 69, 244]]
]
```

This doesn't form any image, just four squares, but I still want to know how to display it.

Note:
I have seen other questions about this, but I want to know how to display 4 squares in a 2x2 grid.

Comment: Create a numpy array: `data = np.array(your_list_of_rgb)` then use `imshow()` function: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imshow(data)`